Pandas how to overcome true problem in if/else logic
I am very new to pandas hence please excuse the simplicity of the question
I have a data frame EURUSD1D and there is a column "Difference" within the data frame
I want a new column "Control" to be created and for each row where the "Difference" is greater than 0 to record the value 12 and if not, then to record the value 22
I wrote below code but get an error saying :ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
for each in EURUSD1D:
if EURUSD1D["Difference"]>0:
    EURUSD1D["Control"]=12 
else:
    EURUSD1D["Control"]=22

Any help would be greatly appreciated

EURUSD1D['Control'] = np.where(EURUSD1D['Difference'] > 0, 12, 22)

Thank you Nick. Your answer worked. However you have replied as a comment and not as an answer...and i dont have any option to mark your answer as correct. Can you recreate it as a answer so i can mark it. Thank u once again

I'm glad that solved your problem. The question has been closed as a duplicate so I can't post an answer.
